# Background color for div over div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 containers within a container..I need to set the background-color of the left-container and right-container but the below code is not working...

fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/4uG4j/
```

html

```
    <div id="container">
       <div id="left-container">
       </div>
       <div id="right-container">
       </div>
    </div>


css


html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:2;
}
#container{
   height:75%;
   background-color:yellow
}
#left-container{
   width:23%;
   background-color:red;
   float:left;
   border:1px solid #254117;
}
#right-container{
   width:75%;
   background-color:green;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: left and right containers do not have `height`set, so they are invisible except the border.

Answer (score 2):

[It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/4uG4j/2/), you just have no content, causing the element's `height` to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `height:100%` on both of them.

**css**

```
#left-container{
   width:23%;
   background-color:red;
   float:left;
   border:1px solid #254117;
   height:100%;
}
#right-container{
   width:75%;
   background-color:green;
   float:left;
   height:100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uG4j/3/)

And i suppose you want the right on to the right so add `float:right` and `width` same as `left-container` as my following example:

**css**

```
#left-container{
   width:23%;
   background-color:red;
   float:left;
   border:1px solid #254117;
   height:100%;
}
#right-container{
   width: 23%;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uG4j/5/)